# Setting HTML content to JTextPane messes up System.out redirection

Tags: java, html, swing, text, html-table

I am using the [MessageConsole](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) class to redirect `System.out` and `System.err` to a `JTextPane` named `jMessageConsoleTextPane`.

**I am configuring it in my constructor like this:**

```
jMessageConsoleTextPane.putClientProperty(JEditorPane.HONOR_DISPLAY_PROPERTIES, Boolean.TRUE);
MessageConsole mc = new MessageConsole(jMessageConsoleTextPane, true);
mc.redirectOut(null, null);
mc.redirectErr(Color.RED, null);
mc.setMessageLines(100);
```

and also in NetBeans I have it set to contentType `text/html`.

It prints everything fine with `System.out` and `System.err` but here comes my problem. I try to set the text of `jMessageConsoleTextPane` to an html table (which contains two other html tables) that I have created based on some variables, **so I do:**

```
String htmlTable = WordCounting.getHtmlTable(wordsArrays, hashtagsArrays);
jMessageConsoleTextPane.setText(htmlTable);
```

**Here is how the `htmlTable` String can look like (taken straight from the debugger):**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <table border="1">
                  <th colspan="3">Words used most</th>
                  <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>day</td>
                     <td>3720</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>2</td>
                     <td>good</td>
                     <td>3354</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>3</td>
                     <td>love</td>
                     <td>2689</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>4</td>
                     <td>time</td>
                     <td>2372</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>5</td>
                     <td>got</td>
                     <td>1897</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>6</td>
                     <td>lot</td>
                     <td>1831</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>7</td>
                     <td>know</td>
                     <td>1801</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>8</td>
                     <td>photo</td>
                     <td>1772</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>9</td>
                     <td>girl</td>
                     <td>1755</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>10</td>
                     <td>life</td>
                     <td>1754</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td>
               <table border="1">
                  <th colspan="3">Hashtags used most</th>
                  <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>win</td>
                     <td>136</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>2</td>
                     <td>panjaforpunjab</td>
                     <td>105</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>3</td>
                     <td>aaronto600k</td>
                     <td>100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>4</td>
                     <td>rt</td>
                     <td>89</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>5</td>
                     <td>giveaway</td>
                     <td>85</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>6</td>
                     <td>cfc</td>
                     <td>70</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>7</td>
                     <td>whybeinarelationshipwhen</td>
                     <td>65</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>8</td>
                     <td>retweet</td>
                     <td>64</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>9</td>
                     <td>gameinsight</td>
                     <td>64</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>10</td>
                     <td>rhoareunion</td>
                     <td>57</td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Here is how it looks in the `jMessageConsoleTextPane`:**

[image: first]

Then I try to use `System.out` which should print bellow text:

```
[23:19:32] Getting driver...
[23:19:32] Connecting to database...
[23:19:32] Executing query...
5.6.16
```

and this happens:

[image: second]

Basically everything is getting added on the last cell of the second table. Even if I do `jMessageConsoleTextPane.setText("")` there is a sole table cell remaining like this (top left):

[image: third]

So what is going on? Why is there a cell left and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MessageConsole` class was not designed to be using with HTML. All the class does is add the text to the end of the Document, which in your case appears to be the last cell of the table.

You can try adding an empty HTML tag to the Document when you first create the HTML. Then maybe the text will be added to this tag instead of the table cell.

Maybe something like:

```
       </table>
   <p></p>
</body>
```

This all depends on how the Document parses the text that is inserted into the Document.

Comment: Using `<p></p>` makes every line having an extra break line but I tried `&nbsp;` and it looks like it works just fine, thank you.